# What is the smallest POSIX OS?

Tags: livecd, posix

What is the smallest POSIX operating system that has a live CD and can be installed?
⠀It must support wifi.
⠀I only need a CLI interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Damn Small Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damn_Small_Linux) weighs in at just 50MB, and there is a list of [Verified Wireless Cards](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/wiki/verified_wireless_cards.html). It is ideal for [business card CDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_CD#Formats) or old 64MB flash cards.

From the [Damn Small Linux website](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/):

> **Damn Small Linux is a very versatile 50MB mini desktop oriented Linux distribution.**
>
> Damn Small is small enough and smart enough to do the following things:
>
> - Boot from a business card CD as a live linux distribution (LiveCD)
> - Boot from a USB pen drive
> - Boot from within a host operating system (that's right, it can run *inside* Windows)
> - Run very nicely from an IDE Compact Flash drive via a method we call "frugal install"
> - Transform into a Debian OS with a traditional hard drive install
> - Run light enough to power a 486DX with 16MB of Ram
> - Run fully in RAM with as little as 128MB (you will be amazed at how fast your computer can be!)
> - Modularly grow -- DSL is highly extendable without the need to customize

Answer (score 2):

Tiny Core Linux wireless version, called CorePlus, weighs in at 72MB and can be run live from a live CD or a USB flash drive. It is recommended by Tiny Core Linux for new users who only have access to a wireless network.

For more information about Tiny Core Linux including screenshots visit the [Tiny Core Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/) website. CorePlus can be downloaded from the [Tiny Core Linux Downloads](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/downloads.html) webpage.